# Cauchy criterion approximation

Tags: cauchy-sequences

I have to use Cauchy's criterion on $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\cos{n}a}{3^n}.$$
Because I'll have the absolute value of it to prove Cauchy and cos n is from [-1,1], so it will actually be from [0,1], can I approximate the fraction to just $\frac{a}{3^n}?$
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $-1 \leq \cos(na) \leq 1$ for any $n$ and $a$.  Also, $\sum_{n=i}^{j-1} \frac{1}{3^n} = \frac{3}{2}(3^{-i}-3^{-j})$ is an easy geometric series.

Comment: But isn't it cos(n)*a? so the whole thing would be between -a and a

Comment: @StefanaPausan : Cosine (and almost all other functions and operators that are written without parentheses) bind the entire next term -- meaning everything up to the next "$+$", "$-$", "$=$", or the end of an enclosing scope (for instance the end of a numerator or denominator written horizontally, or the end of a radical) .  So the argument of cosine here is $na$.

Comment: Ah, ok. Did not know that. Thank you!